# unwanted date picker in visual force page

Tags: visualforce

I' having a problem on a visual force page.  To demonstrate I created this simple page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
<apex:form >

This is a test page

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I would expect the page to just say "This is a test page".  But what I get is "This is a test page" followed by a date picker.

If I remove the apex:form or showHeader=false, I get what I expect.

Comment: Above posted code also giving same result?

Comment: When I create exactly the page you list the date picker does not appear on current Chrome or Firefox. The `datePicker` CSS class has `display: none` set. When I remove the `display: none` using Chrome's Developer Tools the datepicker overlays the "This is a test page" text. Exactly what browser (including version) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome version 33.0.1750.154 m. and view source doesn't show display:none for datePicker.

Comment: @Lance There is a "Styles" tab over to the right in the Chrome "Developer Tools" panel and there you can see (and change) the total set of styles being applied. My Chrome is 34.0.1847.116, which is different to yours. But I was thinking the problem might be in a very different browser e.g. IE7/IE8 etc. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove the datepicker by adding the following to the top of my page

```
<style>
    .datePicker{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

This seems like a bug.  But now I have a workaround.  As long as I don't want a date picker on my pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    setFocusOnLoad();
</script>
```